# Is it possible to get access to the ReFS (codename Protogon) file system on Windows 8 developer preview?

Tags: filesystems, windows-8-preview

There is a fair bit of talk out there about [Protogon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protogon) a rumored new File System for Windows 8.

After having installed the developer preview on bare metal hardware and in a virtual environment and it does not show up as an option for new partitions.

**Is it only an option in the 'leaked' builds of Windows 8 and not the Developer Preview?**

Blog posts about the new file system:

> http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/the-mystery-of-windows-8s-new-protogon-file-system/9567
>
> http://www.winrumors.com/windows-8-includes-new-protogon-file-system-return-of-winfs/
>
> http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-8-found-to-include-new-protogon-filesystem

Comment: yay, another new filesystem a linux driver has to be developed for...

Comment: I don't see the point of Yet Another "File" System. Unless it can cook breakfast. . .

Comment: "Protogon" is the codename used by Microsoft during development. The official name for this filesystem is REFS.

Answer (score 1):

All three of your links have referenced Protogon as a kernel level driver.

But I found it.

`format D:/FS:protogon /Q`

Where D is your drive.

Edit:

http://www.winrumors.com/microsofts-new-windows-8-resilient-file-system-refs-will-be-server-only/

Sounds like Protogon has been renamed to Resilient File System (ReFS).

Comment: Did this work for you? I tried on dedicated hardware install of Win8 and a VM with no luck, just reports: 'format failed' after it starts 'creating file system structures'

Comment: It works on a 500GB Western digital. But it is preview software. Your milage may vary. I'd try a different motherboard.